# Easy inquiry: how to precisely schedule a job in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I want to run a process at a very precise time. Right now I'm using Delayed Job:

```
handle_asynchronously :make_live, :run_at => (exact_time_down_to_the_second)
```

But it isn't precise at all. For instance, when I do:

```
handle_asynchronously :make_live, :run_at => (Time.now + 30.seconds)
```

...it executes in 30 seconds +/- 15 seconds. Subsequent attempts occur within 6 seconds of `Time.now` or so, sometimes nearly instantly.

Is there a precise way to do this? Not stuck on delayed job.

## Edit

When I do:

```
handle_asynchronously :make_live, :run_at => Proc.new {|event| event.occurs_at }
```

...it works well (seems to poll the queue down to the second). Even when using short intervals (30 seconds).

It looks like it's just the console testing that isn't working well.

So that solves my problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

The delay is probably caused by two factors: delayed jobs checks for jobs at regular intervals. Delayed jobs also executes jobs sequentially, so if there happens to be some jobs in the queue already, it gets delayed.

If you know and can define tasks ahead of time (i.e. not relative to current time), use [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem which is a wrapper for cronjobs.

Creating a seperate queue for Delayedjobs can also reduce the delay caused by long queues.

You can also switch to [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque), which is like in-memory queue, which probably checks the queue at shorter intervals.

Comment: I'll check out Whenever. BTW I'm testing with only one job in the queue; the application itself will never have more than 4, spaced a day or so apart.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  Your job wrapper isn't precise enough for you. I see 2 options:

1. Replace or amend the job wrapper to be more precise.  Resque may help, or you could poke at the Delayed::Job internals to poll for jobs more frequently. Doable, but I prefer this hack:
2. Schedule the job for 60 seconds prior to when you need it run. Pass in the exact time you need the job executed, as a parameter. Then, run `sleep until Time.now == exact_time_down_to_the_second`

Boom! Precise execution, down to the second.

Comment: Also, lulalala makes a great point: if you have jobs queued up before this one, Delayed::Job may still not get to the job in time.  It sounds like your app spaces the jobs apart right now, but in the future, if you have other types of jobs, you'll want to have one queue for important tasks like this, and leave your other jobs in a separate queue with a separate worker pool.  

I believe Delayed::Job now supports named queues, or Resque definitely does.  Good luck!

Comment: What will happens if your query length is great? All workers will sleep and query will grow. It's very bad idea.

Comment: The only worker that should sleep in a proper implementation of my solution is the worker running this one critical job. To be safe, you could either wrap the job in a timeout block, or adjust MAX_RUN_TIME accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Delayed Job is set to poll the database every 5 seconds by default. You could adjust this so that it polls every second. I'm curious about the use case that requires this level of precision. Maybe there is a better solution?